# elisp: posn-at-point returns nil after goto-char. How to update the display before posn-at-point?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs lisp, [`posn-at-point`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Mouse.html#index-posn_002dat_002dpoint-1312) is documented as:

> posn-at-point is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>   (posn-at-point &optional POS WINDOW)
>   .
>   Return position information for buffer POS in WINDOW.
>   POS defaults to point in WINDOW; WINDOW defaults to the selected window.
>   .
>   **Return nil if position is not visible in window.**  Otherwise,
>   the return value is similar to that returned by `event-start` for
>   a mouse click at the upper left corner of the glyph corresponding
>   to the given buffer position:
>      (WINDOW AREA-OR-POS (X . Y) TIMESTAMP OBJECT POS (COL . ROW)
>       IMAGE (DX . DY) (WIDTH . HEIGHT))
>   The `posn-` functions access elements of such lists.

ok, now I've got a function that looks something like this:

```
(defun my-move-and-popup-menu ()
  "move the point, then pop up a menu."
    (goto-char xxxx)
    (setq p (posn-at-point))
    (my-popup-menu p ...)
)
```

Basically, move the point, then retrieve the screen position at that point, and then popup a menu at that screen position.

But I am finding that `posn-at-point` returns non-nil, only if the xxxx character position (the *after* position) is visible in the window, *before* the call to `goto-char`.  It seems that the position is not actually updated until exit from the function.  If `goto-char` goes a long way, more than one screenful, then the retrieved position is always nil, and my code doesn't know where to popup the menu.

The reason I suggest that the position is not actually updated until exit from the function - when the menu successfully pops up, the cursor is clearly visible in its previous location while the popup menu is being displayed.  When I dismiss the menu, the cursor moves to where I expected it to move, after the `goto-char` call.

How can I get the position to be *really* updated, between `goto-char` and `posn-at-point`, so that `posn-at-point` will not return nil?

In a Windows Forms application I would call Form.Update() or something similar to update the display in the middle of an event handler.  What's the emacs version of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 (goto-char xxx)
 (redisplay)
```

to enforce displaying of the new position.

Comment: perfect.  Just what I needed.